# positioning in <mat-drawer-container>

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have  and I need to set the data in   so that it is in the center but the  overlaps the data in .

```html
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
  <mat-drawer mode="side" opened position="start">
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor = "let item of Items">
        <td>
          <button mat-stroked-button class="side-button">{{item.value1}}</button> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content class="content">
    <app-component1></app-component1>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

What parameters can help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve problem without parameter. Only using css flex, problem solved. 
You can use this code block;

```css
.outline-example-container {
 height: 100%; 
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center; // for horizontal 
 align-items: center // for vertical
}
```

```html
<div class="outline-example-container">
 <mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
   ....
 </mat-drawer-container>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a solution. It does not change anything. Left table with buttons overlaps the <app-component1>.

Comment: Problem was with table that was inside the mt container. Your solution works. Thanks a lot.